# Is the type product (tuple) operator associative?

Tags: computer-science, type-theory, computer-science-theory

For example, given the types **A**, **B** and **C**: is **A**×**B**×**C**=(**A**×**B**)×**C**=**A**×(**B**×**C**) true, or is the tuple always 'flattened out'? Intuition would tell me that it *is* associative, but on the other hand that would mean tuples of tuples aren't possible. I have found no mention of the properties of the type product operator in any resources I can find - [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) describes product types but doesn't go into great detail about the operator itself.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as "computer-science-theory", wouldn't [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) be a better site to post this question on?

Comment: If you want to know about actual type systems, than it varies, but often (Haskell, Python) `A x B x C /= (A x B) x C /= A x (B x C) /= A x B x C`. cstheory or math sites could tell what it's like in category theory.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I initially went to post on that site, however that seems to be geated more toward research-level CS. I have no formal education in type theory so I was hesitant to post the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it would be associative, but it depends a bit on how you are using it and how much you want (or need) to adhere to its definition. In many type systems, you only have two-type tuples, and every product type that contains more than two types is just two-type tuple where one of the types is another 2-type tuple: `(A, B, C) ~= ((A, B), C)` or `(A, B, C) ~= (A, (B, C))`. Now which of these two you end up with depends on your definition. A simple left-to-right parsing would probably end up with the latter version.

But in the end, it doesn’t really matter. Since this is about type theory, the types are always exactly known; so a tuple of a tuple couldn’t contain some “unknown” tuple. That inner tuple’s types would be known too. And when you know the types, and you know that there is a tuple of tuples, there is not really a difference between `(A, B, (C, D, E))` and `(A, B, C, D, E)`. After all, you know where that “inner tuple” begins and ends. And if the type system requires you to make it `(A, (B, (C, (D, E))))`, then that’s not really a problem either.